# PHP - floatval cuts of position after decimal point?

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    $float = "1,99";
    echo "<p>$float<br>";
    $float = floatval($float); // Without this line number_format throws a notice "A non well formed numeric value encountered" / (float) $float leads to the same output
    $val = number_format($float, 2,'.', ',');
    echo "$float</p>";
?>
```

Why does it return 1? Don't get that.

And: yes, there *is* a sense in converting 1,99 to 1,99 ;-)

Thanks for advise...

Comment: BTW: it is the floatval() that turns 1,99 to 1. Without this line I get a warning but as I'd expect it 1,99...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

floatval recognizes the comma (,) as a character and not as a number, so it cuts off everything that comes after it. In this case, that's the 99. Please use a dot (.) instead of a comma (,) and it will probably work.

Example floatval (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately for germans 1,99 is a valid price whereas 1.99 is a string ;-) so I'm afraid I'll have to str_replace() the comma. Thanks.

Comment: I know the problem. I am dutch so it's the same. As long as you always replace the comma with a dot, you will be fine. Just watch out for numbers like: 2,000.99 .

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, that PHP does not recognize the `,` in `1,99` as a decimal separator. The `float` type is defined as having the following [formal definition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

```
LNUM          [0-9]+
DNUM          ([0-9]*[\.]{LNUM}) | ({LNUM}[\.][0-9]*)
EXPONENT_DNUM [+-]?(({LNUM} | {DNUM}) [eE][+-]? {LNUM})
```

That means it'll only accept `.` as a decimal separator. That's in fact the same reason why `number_format` throws a warning on an invalid datatype because it cannot convert `1,99` to a `float` internally.

The following should work:

```
$float = "1,99";
echo "<p>$float<br>";
$val = number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $float), 2,'.', ',');
echo "$float</p>";
```

Comment: I really hoped I would not have to use something like str_replace. Is it the only or "official" way? Thought floatval() would be intelligent enough to see that it's just the , preventing the 1,99 to be a float... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1,99 is not a valid php float. The issue is your comma (,). In PHP you have to use dot (.) as floating point separator.

```
<?php
    $float = "1.99";
    echo "<p>$float<br>";
    $float = (float)$float; 
    $val = number_format($float, 2,'.', ',');
    echo "$float</p>";
?>
```